# Java Applet Console

Tags: linux, chromium, java-applet

Can anyone tell me how to access the Java Applet Console in Chromium for Linux?

I assumed there would be a Java application packaged with the JRE that would give me access through the command line, but I can't find reference to anything.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.2) (ArchLinux-6.b24_1.11.2-1-i686)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553221/linux-ubuntu-java-plugin-and-console and http://java.com/en/download/help/enable_console_linux.xml

Comment: @HackToHell Should have mentioned I'm using IcedTea and OpenJDK. I cannot see an equivilent application.

Answer (score 0):

I found that running Chromium through the command line causes Java Applet output to be posted to `stdout`.

However, I'd still like to know if there is a different answer to this question.